# Surface Volume 3D Analyst Tool - ArcGIS Pro 3.1.2

Tags: arcgis-pro, 3d-analyst, bathymetry, volume

I'm trying to calculate the volume above the plane of a bathymetric data using the 3D Analyst Tool (surface volume). I keep getting the error *"ERROR 000196: error in accessing Extract_PHS1
"* (where Extract_PHS1 is the DEM that I'm using) I have tried to process the tool using .bag and .tif files and the error persists regardless of the file format. I have also tried to export the dataset and save the project before using the tool.

The project is in GDA 94 zone 50 (EPSG:28350)

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

[image]

[image]